# Setting an alarm in a role

Tags: perl, oop, ipc, moose, alarm

I've got a bunch of classes that do different operations over the network, and as we all know, network operations sometimes time-out. So I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
package My::Role::NetworkFetcher { 
    use Moose::Role;

    sub BUILD { 
        my $self = shift;
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { 
            $self->handle_timeout;
        };

        alarm 60;
    }

    sub handle_timeout { 
        die "default timeout handler";
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this. It *seems* to work OK in my very simple test cases, but I'm not sure if hijacking the object's `BUILD` method or localizing a signal handler in this way is correct or even advisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful here. The **local $SIG{ALRM}** only applies to the BUILD method, so if you leave the scope of the function without making a call to **alarm 0**, then the default ALRM handler will happen if you left the BUILD method and the timeout occurs. It is safest to do the entire thing within an eval so you don't run into obscure problems.

Comment: That's actually my intent -- basically these are classes that execute certain jobs that come in from a queue, one per process. I want to set up the timeout in such a way that if the job takes more than a minute, the process dies and logs an error.

Comment: Then you've got nothing to worry about. What you posted looks good to me.